# Angular 6 вызов script js файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

У меня `Angualar 6` и я вызываю  script js файлов но они не работают, что советуйте как еще сделать? В `angular.json` тоже попробовал тоже самое

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/core.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/script.js"
            ]
```

**Структура**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит они не работают?

Comment: В Inspect element показывает что скрипт файл был загружен. но оно просто не работает как будто его нету, думаю это может от того что Angular  работает быстро, не знаю как это организовать. Вот даже онлайн ссылки поставил но нечего не изменилось.
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Lx4w/3sY5Yy7jP

Comment: это не связано с тем что ангуляр работает быстро) у меня в стране недоступен майл.ру, сделайте консоль.лог в вашем скрипте и посмотрите отработает он или нет

Comment: Можно и так сказать, нашел временный решения написав его в `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение вызвать `script` вот так

```
declare var $: any;

ngOnInit() {
    $.getScript('assets/js/script.js');
  }
```